# How do I repair a corrupt file on a ZFS replica?

Tags: linux, backup, zfs

I have two machines: one that has the main 24TB ZFS filestore and one that is a clone of that filestore as a backup. Every now and then, I create a new snapshot on the primary and perform a differential `zfs send` to the backup machine. The primary is raidz3 but the secondary is just striped.

Recently, the backup copy found a corrupt file during a routine scrub. The file is not corrupt on the primary filestore, so if it were two working filesystems, I could just copy the good file to the backup and be done with it. But with the `zfs send` to `zfs recv` workflow, I'm not sure how to handle it. What is the best approach to correcting this corruption so that I maintain the ability to do the differential `zfs send`? I suppose I could modify the file on the primary machine and hope that it gets pushed as part of the next backup, but I'm not even 100% sure what kind of change to that file would trigger it being refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to rewrite the entire file for all the blocks to change. Assuming you aren't using deduplication, something like this should work:

```
cat brokenfile > brokenfile2
mv brokenfile2 brokenfile
zfs snapshot ...
zfs send
```

That should get you a complete working file in the backup server.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I will give this a try and report back.

Comment: For anyone's reference ... this worked fine. I had to eventually zap the snapshot containing the corrupt file and force ZFS to re-scrub before all the errors went away.