# ZFS checksum error: how to recover from a replica?

Tags: zfs, truenas, openzfs

ZFS can automatically repair checksum errors if the drive with the error is part of a pool set up with redundancy.

What about the case when the checksum error is on a pool without redundancy, but there is a replicated snapshot elsewhere? Can the broken block be copied with `zfs send` or similar?

For example, let's say there is a primary pool `tank` that has automatic snapshots and replication to a backup pool `backup`. Think of `backup` as a single drive. A scrub of `backup` finds an unrecoverable checksum error. The valid blocks are still available on `tank`. Is it possible to recover this checksum error from `tank`?

[This manual file copy method](https://serverfault.com/a/1034511/184095) is the closest I've found, but it leaves much to be desired. Is there a cleaner way that can be automated?

Comment: Use a pool with redundancy.